# Simple function call inside module, getting NaN, huh?

Tags: javascript, nan

Here is the module i am working on:

```
var FeatureRotator = (function($,global) {
    var self = {},
        currentFeature = 0,
        images = [],
        imagePrefix = "/public/images/features/",
        timer = null,        
        totalImages = 0,
        initialFeature,
        interval,
        blendSpeed,
        element = null,
        img1 = null,
        img2 = null;

    function setVisibleImage(iid) {
        $("#img1").attr('src',images[iid].src).css('opacity',1);
        $("#img2").css('opacity',0);
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $("#f"+iid).addClass("active");
    }

    function setCurrentImage(id) {
        currentFeature = id;
        setVisibleImage(id);
    }

    function doHoverIn(position) {
        if (currentFeature === position) {
            self.pause();
        } else {
            setCurrentImage(global.parseInt(position, 10));
            self.pause();
        }
    }

    function doHoverOut(position) {
        self.unpause();
    }

    self.init = function(options,callback) {
        var i = 0,
            tempImg = null;

        interval = options.interval || 5000;
        blendSpeed = options.blendSpeed || 500;
        element = options.element;
        initialFeature = options.initialFeature || 0;
        img1 = $("<img/>").attr('id','img1');
        img2 = $("<img/>").attr('id','img2').css('opacity','0').css('margin-top',-options.height);

        $(element).append(img1).append(img2);

        totalImages = $(".feature").size();

        for (i = 0;i < totalImages; i++) {
            tempImg = new global.Image();
            tempImg.src = imagePrefix +"feature_" + i + ".png";
            images.push(tempImg);


            $("#f"+i).css('background-image',
                            'url("'+imagePrefix+"feature_"+i+"_thumb.png"+'")')
                     .hover(doHoverIn($(this).attr('position'))
                     , doHoverOut($(this).attr('position'))
                     ).attr('position',i);
        }

        setVisibleImage(initialFeature);

        if (options.autoStart) {
            self.start();
        }
        if (callback !== null) {
            callback();
        }
    };

    function updateImage() {        
        var active = $("#img1").css('opacity') === 1 ? "#img1" : "#img2";
        var nextFeature = (currentFeature === totalImages-1 ? 0 : currentFeature+1);

        if (active === "#img1") {
            $("#img2").attr('src',images[nextFeature].src);            
            $("#img2").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 1);            
            $("#img1").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 0);
        } else {
            $("#img1").attr('src',images[nextFeature].src);            
            $("#img1").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 1);            
            $("#img2").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 0);
        }

        $("#f"+currentFeature).removeClass("active");
        $("#f"+nextFeature).addClass("active");

        currentFeature = nextFeature;
    }



    self.start = function() {
        currentFeature = initialFeature;
        setVisibleImage(currentFeature);
        timer = global.setInterval(function(){
            updateImage();
        }, interval);
    };        

    self.pause = function() {
        global.clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    self.unpause = function() {
        timer = global.setInterval(function(){
            updateImage();
        }, interval);
    };


    return self;
}(this.jQuery, this));
```

And here is how it is used on the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // ...

        $(function() {
            FeatureRotator.init({
                interval:5000,
                element:'#intro',
                autoStart:true,
                height:177,
                blendSpeed:1000,
                initialFeature:0
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The problem is, when setVisibleImage is called from the init method, the value of iid is NaN. I've stepped through the debugger and verified that 'initialFeature' is 0 when the setVisibleImage function is called, but alas, the value doesn't make it over there.

Can anyone help me determine what the problem is? I've run the code through JSLint, and it came back clean.

**UPDATE**

Ok here is my updated code, which works now except the fading doesnt work, the image just flips to the next one and doesn't fade smoothly anymore:

```
var FeatureRotator = (function($,global) {
    var self = {},
        currentFeature = 0,
        images = [],
        imagePrefix = "/public/images/features/",
        timer = null,        
        totalImages = 0,
        initialFeature = 0,
        interval,
        blendSpeed;


    function setVisibleImage(iid) {
        $("#img1").attr('src',images[iid].src).css('opacity',1);
        $("#img2").css('opacity',0);
        $(".active").removeClass("active");
        $("#f"+iid).addClass("active");
    }

    function setCurrentImage(id) {
        currentFeature = id;
        setVisibleImage(id);
    }

    function doHoverIn(obj) {
        var position = global.parseInt(obj.target.attributes["position"].value,10);

        if (currentFeature === position) {
            self.pause();
        } else {
            setCurrentImage(global.parseInt(position, 10));
            self.pause();
        }
    }

    function doHoverOut() {
        self.unpause();
    }

    self.init = function(options,callback) {
        var i = 0,
            tempImg = null,
            element = null,
            img1 = null,
            img2 = null;

        interval = options.interval || 5000;
        blendSpeed = options.blendSpeed || 500;
        element = options.element;
        initialFeature = options.initialFeature || 0;
        img1 = $("<img/>").attr('id','img1');
        img2 = $("<img/>").attr('id','img2').css('opacity','0').css('margin-top',-options.height);

        $(element).append(img1).append(img2);

        totalImages = $(".feature").size();

        for (i = 0;i < totalImages; i++) {
            tempImg = new global.Image();
            tempImg.src = imagePrefix +"feature_" + i + ".png";
            images.push(tempImg);


            $("#f"+i).css('background-image','url("'+imagePrefix+"feature_"+i+"_thumb.png"+'")')
                     .hover(doHoverIn, doHoverOut)
                     .attr('position',i);
        }

        setVisibleImage(initialFeature);

        if (options.autoStart) {
            self.start();
        }
        if (typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    };

    function updateImage() {        
        var active = $("#img1").css('opacity') === 1 ? "#img1" : "#img2";
        var nextFeature = (currentFeature === totalImages-1 ? 0 : currentFeature+1);

        if (active === "#img1") {
            $("#img2").attr('src',images[nextFeature].src);            
            $("#img2").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 1);            
            $("#img1").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 0);
        } else {
            $("#img1").attr('src',images[nextFeature].src);            
            $("#img1").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 1);            
            $("#img2").fadeTo(blendSpeed, 0);
        }

        $("#f"+currentFeature).removeClass("active");
        $("#f"+nextFeature).addClass("active");

        currentFeature = nextFeature;
    }



    self.start = function() {
        currentFeature = initialFeature;
        setVisibleImage(currentFeature);
        timer = global.setInterval(function(){
            updateImage();
        }, interval);
    };

    self.stop = function() {
        global.clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    self.pause = function() {
        global.clearTimeout(timer);
    };

    self.unpause = function() {
        timer = global.setInterval(function(){
            updateImage();
        }, interval);
    };


    return self;
}(this.jQuery, this));
```

Comment: Did you check the value of `initialFeature` immediately before calling `setVisibleImage()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're getting `NaN`, I'm guessing it is actually taking place from this line:

```
.hover(doHoverIn($(this).attr('position'))
```

...which calls this:

```
setCurrentImage(global.parseInt(position, 10)); // note the parseInt()
```

...which calls this:

```
setVisibleImage(id);
```

So the `position` being passed to `parseInt` is coming from `$(this).attr('position')`, which is likely an value that can't be parsed into a Number, so you get `NaN`.

Check out the value of that attribute in first line of the block for the `for` statement.

```
for (i = 0;i < totalImages; i++) {
    console.log( $(this).attr('position') ); // verify the value of position
    // ...
```

Comment: ok got it working, mostly, updated my code, getting another issue now, if you would be able to take a look and see whats going on? I can hit those fadeTo methods, and the blendSpeed value is correct

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out...the 'active' var in updateImage was always getting set to #img2 because i was using === and the css value was coming in as a string instead of an integer, i changed it to == and it works again, which was the way i had it before jslint told me to change it, which makes sense. i should parse the opacity value into an integer so that i know i'm comparing apples to apples.